# How many people in a FaceBook Profile Picture?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

So I want to count how many people appear in a facebook profile picture.
Typically there are 0-2 people (sometimes there are 4-5+ but that's more rare).

A sample dataset (and a few tries using python) can be found here:

https://github.com/yoniker/FaceDetect

I've tried different methods, none of them give reasonable results (all of those methods are wrong most of the time),I've tried the following:

-Face detection- http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html

It usually doesn't find anyone (that happens at around 75% of the pictures)- and I have tried different Haar filters and parameters.

-Pedestrian Detection http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/09/pedestrian-detection-opencv/
Again it doesn't find people most of the time.

OpenFace:Probably this face recognition algo doesn't truly help with face detection (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cmu-openface/X6erXKckk0Q).

And finally I've looked at different StackOverflow questions such as 
[Count the number of people in the video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060477/count-the-number-of-people-in-the-video) but none of them are relevant!

I've tried for half a day now- so help will be super appreciated!!

Comment: well obviously face detection should be one solution to this problem. but if you just say you tried and failed no one will be able to tell you what you did wrong and how to fix it...
provide an image, show what you did, which results you expected and what you got instead

Comment: Showing the results will involve sharing many jpg files.I am saying that none of the methods I have mentioned detect faces well in an arbitrary setting (and honestly I am not too sure about which setting those are working well). If you have found any of those to be doing well, do let me know which one.  Again : I am saying that most of the time, those are simply wrong (most of the time not finding someone when there is someone, eg 0/1 or 1/2 people's faces are detected).

Answer (score 2):

For me, [dlib](http://dlib.net) has given better results than using OpenCV's haar face detector. It has python bindings too. You can find quick-start code to do face detection [here](http://dlib.net/face_detector.py.html).

It would be possible to help better if you post an Image in which faces are not detected properly.

Having said that, to improve face detection apart from using dlib, you can experiment with these ideas:

- Use histogram equalisation(equalizeHist on opencv) on gray scale image before passing it to face detector. (i.e preprocess your images)
- If faces are tilted to left or right, more often face detection fails. To solve this rotate the images in steps of 5 degrees upto 30 degrees and apply face detection. At each rotation you might detect new faces.
- Most face detectors which are not using deep learning detect mostly frontal faces. Not much could be done about this apart from using deep learning or train your own side profile face detector using HOG or HAAR features.

Hope this helps you to improve your face detection.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot, however I must say that in the real world of Facebook Profile pics, many faces are not "frontal faces". I want to train my net on a different problem , so I was hoping to use someone else's net for just detecting people :) Any suggestions? (I was looking at openface but see the link i have posted- that specific net isn't doing well at detection either!).

Comment: Yes, that is true about frontal faces. Then deep learning is the way to go I guess. Try this https://github.com/quanhua92/darknet/. I have not used it myself, but I remember one of my friend telling me about this to detect face. I am guessing this should work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks,you were right about dlib working much better than HAAR! However like you suggested this is far from perfect, I've uploaded a small dataset so you can see exactly where it fails at https://github.com/yoniker/FaceDetect. I will check out darknet now and let you know,either way you were very helpful already :)

Comment: Cool! glad to help. Hope darknet works for you. I will take a look at the images you shared today/tomorrow.

Comment: There is a more accurate deep learning based face detector in dlib: http://blog.dlib.net/2016/10/easily-create-high-quality-object.html?m=1

Comment: Davis that most def should be an answer rather than a comment - I've almost missed it! I most def have to take a closer deeper look at your work since it might have some serious implications!!

Answer (score 0):

There's always the cascade classifier in OpenCV for all your face detection needs. If you could feed it with some nice features it would give you all the results.